# How do I install Chocolatey in a different location than standard, say, even on a different partition?

Tags: windows-7, package-management, chocolatey

I would like to install Chocolatey on a separate partition. Is this possible, or do I have to take the default `C:\`?
I currently have `E:\` partition where I install all my software. I would like all my `cinst` packages to go there.
Is this just a function of changing the `PATH` variable, after installing Chocolatey, or do I have to do something more substantial?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install Chocolatey exactly where you would like, and to make that easier, there's even [some information written up on the wiki for Chocolatey about that](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/Installation#before-you-install)!

1. Create a **user environment** variable named `ChocolateyInstall` and set it to the folder you want chocolatey to install to prior to installation.
2. Create the folder manually.
3. Install Chocolatey.

### The simple and "automated" way

If you'd like to keep it simple, simply open upen an administrative session of **PowerShell** (if you need so), and run the following snippet. It'll do the steps above.

```
Set-Variable -Name "ChocolateyInstall" -Value (Read-Host -Prompt "Install location")
New-Item $ChocolateyInstall -Type Directory -Force
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ChocolateyInstall", $ChocolateyInstall, "User")
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

*Always be careful, and read snippets of code before executing it.*

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I read and misunderstood that to mean the variable had to be in 'system partition'. Apologies.

Comment: @runtime_error Stuff happens! I added a complete/simple way to do it.

Comment: Seems the chocolatey docs not really helpfull. Chocolatey install guide should be arranged like this answer.